# Pull data from column to Listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets (Sheet1,Sheet2), which contain different data. In VBA, I have 2 listbox, one for display the Column A (Sheet1) and one for display the Column A (Sheet2). When I execute my coding,the listbox1 and listbox2 keep on showing the ActiveSheet Column A's Data, not Sheet1's data or Sheet2's data separately.

```
With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "50"
    .RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Address
End With

With ListBox2
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "50"
    .RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Address
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Address` and `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Address`, It will always give you `$A:$A` and it will refer to the activesheet.

Try this instead

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!" & _
             Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Address
```

or

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!" & "A:A"
```

Similarly for **Listbox2**

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & _
             Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Address
```

or

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & "A:A"
```

---

**BTW** I recommend finding the last row of the column using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then creating your `.RowSource`

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!" & _
             Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LRow1).Address
```

or

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!" & "A:A" & LRow1
```

Similarly for **Listbox2**

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & _
             Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & LRow2).Address
```

or

```
.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & "A:A" & LRow2
```

Comment: Done,Thank Siddharth for your advice too.

Comment: What is the use of ! in (.RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & "A:A" & LRow2) situation? i can't find it at website.

Comment: By specifying `!` we are telling excel where does the `A:A` column is. If we do not do that then it will assume that you meant `activesheet`

Comment: Try referencing a cell in Sheet1 to another cell in Sheet2. Note the formula and you will know

Comment: 1 more thing is,How to select the rowsource start from A2 to the last row instead of A1. I get error when i try .RowSource = Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "!" & "A2:A" & LRow2

Comment: You need to find last row `LRow2` first as shown in the link in my answer